# Stone Cech compactification of $(0,1]$is not $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, compactification

> If I considered $(0,1]\subset \beta(0,1]=[0,1]$ this is trivial because the universal property would mean we would need a continuos function on $[0,1]$ with $g(t)=\sin(1/t)$ fot all $t \in(0,1]$ which is clearly absurd (no $g(0)$ makes $g$ continuous). I do not want to use this continence, because I only assume $\beta(0,1]\approx [0,1]$ and so, $(0,1]$ could be "scrambled inside" of $[0,1]$.

Here is what I tried so far:

I am interested in proving the Stone Cech compactification of $(0,1]$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.

Because $[-1,1]$ is a Hausdorff compact space, the universal property of the Stone Cech compactification teaches us there would be a unique continuos map $g:\beta (0,1]\rightarrow[-1,1] $ such that $g(\epsilon(t))=\sin(1/t)$ where $\epsilon$ is the evaluation function given by $\epsilon(t)=(f(t))_{f\in C_b(0,1]}$.

Let $\Phi: \beta(0,1]\rightarrow [0,1] $ be a homeomorphism. In this case, $g\Phi^{-1}\Phi\epsilon(t)=\sin(1/t)$ for $1\geq t>0$. My initial tought was taking $t=\frac{1}{n}$ in this case $\Phi\epsilon(1/n)\in [0,1]$ is bounded and by Bolzano Weierstrass there is a convergent subsequence, such that $\Phi\epsilon(1/n_k)\rightarrow x_o$. So, we have $\sin(n_k)=\sin(1/(1/n_k))\rightarrow g\Phi^{-1}(x_o)$. I thought this would be a contradiction but it appears there are always (Bolzano Weierstrass again) convergent subsequences of the form $\sin(n_k)$, so it could be $\sin(n_k)$ indeed converges.

Comment: How about showing $|\beta(0,1]| = 2^{\mathfrak c}$

Comment: I am only familiar with countable/uncountable types of set. Would you recommend any material in particular if I wanted to study what $2^c$ and other more sophisticated cardinalities mean?

Comment: @GEdgar How on Earth do you do that?

Comment: @FShrike ... Discrete $\mathbb N$ is homeomoprhic to a closed setset of $(0,1]$, namely $\{1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\dots\}$.  So $\beta \mathbb N$ embeds (injectively) into $\beta (0,1]$.  And $|\beta\mathbb N| = 2^{\mathfrak c}$ is known.

Comment: @GEdgar Ah. And because $\Bbb N$ is discrete, $\beta\Bbb N$ is just the ultrafilter space. Is it easy to see that there are $2^c$ ultrafilters on $\Bbb N$?

Comment: Easy?  No.  Here is one https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83540/442

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stone Cech compactification is the biggest compactification of a  completely regular space, the one-point compactification is the smallest compactification of a locally  compact space.

Clearly $[0,1]$ is the one-point compactification of $(0,1]$. If it also were the Stone Cech compactification of $(0,1]$, then each map $f : (0,1] \to K$ to a compact Hausdorff space $K$ would have a (unique) continuous extension $\bar f : [0,1] \to K$.

The space $(0,1]$ has many compactifications, for example the closed topologist's sine-curve $T$. See [Non-equivalent compactifications of $[0, \infty)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4610897). The identity on $(0,1]$ should therefore have a continuous extension $\phi = \bar id : [0,1] \to T$. Since $(0,1]$ is dense in $T$, we have $\phi([0,1]) = T$ which implies that $\phi(\{0\})$ is the remainder $R = T \setminus(0,1]$. But this is impossible because $R$ has more than one point.

**Update:**

$\phi(\{0\}) = R$ is a consequence of the following general

**Lemma.** Let $f : X \to Y$ be a continuous map from a compact space $X$ to a Hausdorff space $Y$ such that $f(X)$ contains a dense subspace $B \subset Y$. Then $f(X) = Y$. In particular the remainder $R = Y \setminus B$ is contained in $f(X)$.

*Proof.* $f(X)$ is a compact subset of $Y$, thus it is closed in $Y$. We have $Y = \overline B  \subset \overline{f(X)} = f(X)$, hence $f(X) = Y$. $\quad \square$

Now consider $\phi : [0,1] \to T$. It maps $(0,1]$ bijectively onto the dense subspace $(0,1]$ of $T$. The Lemma shows that the remainder $R$ must be contained in $\phi([0,1])$. Thus $\phi(\{0\}) = R$.

**Update:**

Let us be a bit more formal.

The Stone Cech compactification is a dense embedding $i : (0,1] \to \beta(0,1]$ into a compact Hausdorff space $\beta(0,1]$ satisfying the well-known universal property. Often one says that the space $\beta(0,1]$ **is** the Stone Cech compactification, but the embedding $i$ is an essential part of the construct.

Assume that there exists a homeomorphism $h : \beta(0,1] \to [0,1]$. Then $\epsilon = h \circ i : (0,1] \to [0,1]$ is a dense embedding which also has the universal property. Using this $\epsilon$  we could show that it is possible to replace $h$ by a homeomorphism $h' : \beta(0,1] \to [0,1]$ such that $\epsilon' = h' \circ i : (0,1] \to [0,1]$ is the inclusion $\iota : (0,1] \hookrightarrow [0,1]$ which would imply that $\iota$ must have the universal property. But we shall not need this.

Since $\epsilon((0,1])$ is connected, it must be a subinterval of $[0,1]$. The only two dense subintervals which are homeomorphic to $(0,1]$ are $(0,1]$ and $[0,1)$. The remainder $R_\epsilon = [0,1] \setminus \epsilon((0,1])$  is therefore a set with one element.

By the universal property the embedding $f : (0,1] \to T, f(t) = (t, \sin(1/t))$ admits a continuous $\bar f : [0,1] \to T$ such that $\bar f \circ \epsilon = f$. The Lemma implies that that the remainder $R = T \setminus f((0,1])$ is in the image of $\bar f$. Therefore we must have $R = \bar f(R_\epsilon)$. This is a contradiction because $R$ is an infinite set.

Comment: @Kadmos Okay, it was a bit fast. We know that $\phi([0,1])$ is a compact subspace of $T$ which contains $(0,1]$ (more precisely, the graph of the $\sin(1/x)$-curve). But the closure of this subspace is $T$, thus the closure  $T$ must be be contained in $\phi([0,1])$.

Comment: Sorry, now I am confused again. $i: (0,1]\rightarrow \beta (0,1] $ is the inclusion, $h:\beta(0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ is the homeomorphism and $f:\beta(0,1]\rightarrow T$ is the extension. We are taking $\phi=f\circ h^{-1}:[0,1]\rightarrow T$, right? We know $\phi( h\circ \epsilon (0,1] )$ is dense in $T$ hence  $\phi$ is onto. How do we know $[0,1]$ discarding $h\circ \epsilon(0,1]$ consists of only one point?

Comment: @Kadmos I do not understand what your doubt is. If $[0,1]$ were the  Stone Cech compactification of $(0,1]$, then we would have a homeomorphism $h : \beta(0,1] \to (0,1]$ such that $h \circ i$ is the inclusion $(0,1] \hookrightarrow [0.1]$. Therefore $[0,1] \setminus (h \circ i)((0,1]) = \{0\}$.

Comment: Another way to see it is this: Each compactifcation of $(0,1]$ is a dense embedding $\epsilon : (0,1] \to K$ into a compact Hausdorff $K$. There are many dense embeddingsf $\epsilon : (0,1] \to [0,1]$, but the remainder is always a singleton (either $\{0\}$ or $\{1\}$). Now  we assume that $\epsilon$ has the universal property of the Stone Cech compactification and get a contradiction.

Comment: $h\epsilon$ is injective and continuous but I don’t see why it could (without loss of generality) be taken as inclusion… I guess that is mainly what I am still not understanding. Thank you for the edit by the way.

Comment: @Kadmon Whatever $h$ looks like , $\epsilon = h \circ i$ embeds $(0,1]$ as a dense subspace into $[0,1]$. As an embedding $\epsilon$ must be strictly increasing or strictly increasing. Its dense image $J = \epsilon((0,1])$ must therefore be either $J = (0,1]$ or $J = [0,1)$. Clearly $\epsilon$ extends to a homeomorphism $\bar \epsilon : [0,1] \to [0,1]$. Replacing $h$ by $h' = \bar \epsilon^{-1} \circ h$ yields a new $\epsilon' = h' \circ i = \bar \epsilon^{-1} \circ h \circ i = \bar \epsilon^{-1} \circ \epsilon$. But this map is the inclusion $(0,1] \hookrightarrow [0,1]$.