A simply connected space has a simply connected compactification and non-simply connected compactification?
$\mathbb{R}$ is an example of a simply-connected space with non-simply connected compactification (one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{S}^1$ so not simply connected.) but 2-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ is simply-connected.
So a simply connected space might or might not have simply connected compactifications.
Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff  simply connected space. Are the following true?

There exists Hausdorff compactification $C_1$ of $X$ such that $C_1$ is not simply connected.

There exists compactification $C_2$ of $X$ such that $C_2$ is simply connected. (but $C_2$ is not necessarily Hausdorff)



Those voting to close should provide feedback in the comments.

Given any space $X$ you can define its compactification $Y:= X\sqcup {p}$, where the only open subset of $Y$ containing $p$ is $Y$ itself. Then $Y$ is simply connected. But this $Y$ is usually non-Hausdorff. Would you be satisfied with such compactifications?

I’m pretty sure every (Hausdorff) compactification of $X=[0,\infty)$ in which $X$ is open is simply connected, in fact contractible.

According to pi-base, the long ray is simply connected, but its only Hausdorff compactification, the closed long ray, is not.

@Moishe Kohan: is $X \sqcup {p}$ the one-point compactification of $X$?
Then, in fact, this is an example of a possibly not simply connected space, as pointed out by the OP. On the other hand, it might also be simply connected, see the comment of David Gao.

Anyway,  @ talekhine, please specify, whether you want to consider Hausdorff compactifications, only. It certainly makes up a very big difference.

@Ulli The example of Moishe Kohan is not the usual one-point compactification of $X$. Instead, the only open neighborhood of the added point $p$ is $X \sqcup {p}$. An example of such a construction can be found in, for example, here. It is highly non-Hausdorff (in fact, even highly non-$T_1$). But a space that has a point whose only neighborhood is the entire space will be contractible and thus also simply connected. See here.

@David Gao: Oh yes, I should have read more carefully. Thank you for clarification!

@DavidGao $[0,\infty)$ has many Hausdorff compactifcations which are not even path connected. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4610897/349785.

@PaulFrost Ah, you’re right. I thought I had a proof that they are all contractible, but I was badly mistaken. Hmm, I’m now wondering if the Stone-Čech compactification of a non-compact LCH space is ever path-connected. Your example shows it is not for $[0, \infty)$ (and easily generalizes to $\mathbb{R}$ as well - I think it also generalizes to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the half space of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n \geq 1$, maybe even to all non-compact manifolds with/without boundary?). Ulli’s example shows it is not for the long ray.

The Stone-Chech compactification of a normal noncompact (locally compact, Haussdorff) space is never path-connected. I am not sure if normality can be dropped.

In Question 1 you want the further assumption that $X$ is not compact.

@MoisheKohan are you sure this holds without assuming that $X$ is realcompact (or that $\nu X$ is normal)?

@Jakobian: Yes, I am sure.

@MoisheKohan I see this now, and I wrote this and some of my other takes on $\beta X$ not being path-connected in here. For example, theorem 3 implies that Moore plane is a path-connected non-normal Tychonoff space with its Stone-Cech compactification not path-connected.

@Jakobian: My proof seems to be different, but maybe the difference is superficial. See below.

@MoisheKohan Its not actually different, its more verbose and uses the weaker result (which my proof in the link also used before I replaced normality with pseudonormality). But I believe the one for pseudonormality would look pretty much the same when the details are made explicit.

Even more generally normality can be replaced by "property $D$": that for any disjoint closed $A, B\subseteq X$ with $A$ countable and discrete, there exists disjoint open $U, V$ with $A\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq V$. This includes normal, pseudonormal and countably compact spaces. A locally compact non-compact space with property $D$ is such that $\beta X$ is not path-connected.


Suppose that $X$ is a locally compact normal noncompact Hausdorff space. In particular, $X$ is completely regular and, hence, the canonical embedding $\iota: X\to \beta X$ from $X$ to its Stone–Čech compactification, is a topological embedding with open image (which I will identify with $X$ itself). I claim that $\beta X$ cannot be path-connected, moreover, there is no continuous path connecting any point $x\in X$ to any point $y\in Y:=\beta X\setminus X$. Indeed, suppose such path exist. Then, since $X$ is open in $\beta X$, without loss of generality, we can assume that such a path has the form $p: [0,1]\to \beta X$, $p([0,1))\subset X$, $p(1)=y\in  Y$. Then $p: [0,1)\to X$ is a proper map. Consider two sequences $s_n, t_n\in [0,1)$ converging to $1$ and having disjoint images $A$ and $B$ respectively. After passing to subsequences, we can assume that $p$ is injective on the images of $(t_n)$ and $(s_n)$. By the construction, $A\cup B$ is closed in $X$. Define a continuous map $g: A\cup B\to [0,1]$ by
$$
g(p(s_n))= s_n, g(p(t_n))=1-t_n. 
$$
Since $X$ was assumed to be normal, by  Tietze–Urysohn extension theorem, $g$ extends to a continuous map $f: X\to [0,1]$. By the universal property of the
Stone–Čech compactification, the map $f$ extends to a continuous map $F: \beta X\to [0,1]$.  Since $p$ was a continuous map and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} p(s_n)= \lim_{n\to\infty} p(t_n)=y,
$$
we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} F(p(s_n))= \lim_{n\to\infty} F(p(t_n))= F(y). 
$$
However, by the construction, $F(p(s_n))=s_n, F(p(t_n))=1-t_n$ and, thus, these sequences have distinct limits in $[0,1]$ (respectively, $1$ and $0$).
This is a contradiction. Hence, $\beta X$ is not path-connected. This answers half of your question.

The answer to the second half is in my earlier comment, here it is for the sake of completeness.


Let $X$ be any topological space. Define a new topological space $Y=X\sqcup \{a\}$ where open subsets in $Y$ are either open subsets of $X$ or (if they contain $a$) are equal to the entire $Y$. Of course, $Y$ is only Hausdorff if $X=\emptyset$. Nevertheless, $Y$ is a compactification of $X$: Clearly every open cover of $Y$ contains $Y$ as one of its elements, hence, admits a finite subcover. Furthermore, the inclusion $X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism to its image and the image is dense in $Y$. I claim that $Y$ is contractible, hence, simply-connected.  Indeed, define a map $H: Y\times [0,1]\to Y$ by $H(y,t)=y$,  $t<1$ and
$H(y,1)=a$ for all $y\in Y$. Let's check that this map is continuous: If $U\subset X$ is open, then $H^{-1}(U)=U\times [0,1)$. If $U=Y$, then $H^{-1}(U)=Y\times [0,1]$. And there are no other open subsets of $Y$. Hence, $H$ is continuous.
Edit. The true question, I think, is about existence of a compactification with is path-connected but not simply-connected. However, one can prove that $[0,1)$ does not have one.
